# call remote webservice using c sharp soap 1.1 with xml data? how to

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

here I am calling a webservice using ajax jquery now I want to do the same job with soap 1.1 xml data

[w3school method link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp)

I am using the same method above now I want to do with soap 1.1 asp.net using xml c sharp

I tried to give web link as web refrence in advance option also but it says

> schema not match

can you give me a link to code project aso.net soap 1.1 with xml  link or any step by step method what to do with that data

```
 <data>
    <row>
       <code>AAA</code>
       <description>PIA </description>
   </row>
   <row>
       <code>AAB</code>
       <description>UK AIRline</description>
   </row>
 ...........so on
   </data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to read the xml file using Soap 1.1.

Soap is a protocol (Simple Object Access Protocol), not a file type. It happens to use xml as a way to map the hierarchical structure of the objects, but it is not going to be able to pick up an xml file and just use it.

Soap web services like you tried to add use xsd to define a schema and that is represented by the WSDL file (Web Service Definition Language).

Your best bet for this is to make a web request to the url of the xml file and then handle the file in code.

Something like:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/cd_catalog.xml");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

EDIT:
To do a POST request:

```
public static string RunHttpRequest(string url, object obj)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            var json = JsoNify(obj);

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    private static string JsoNify(object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
    }
```

Comment: hey genious are you free today keep in touch at 7pm PST nouman.arshad7 skype i want to learn some thing more

Comment: can this xml doc will be returned as json

Comment: link is this want to search flights 'http://developer.travelpack.com/search-links.php?option=flights'  this will; retun xml i have to post that @Vaelen

Comment: remove '%27' at end of url